# Use the Chain Rule to find dzds and dzdt.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

[image]

so I tried using the chain rule for dz/ds and started with first d second + second d first and used the chain rule by plugging in the value of r and 0 when taking the derivatives but my answer is completely different than the books answer... can someone show me the steps real detailed explaining each step so I can just make sure I'm doing this the right way again? After reading my notes I thought I was supposed to do the multiplication rule combined with the chain rule but it's coming out differently..

Comment: It seems that in the past, others have done the mathematical typesetting before you on every question. Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Follow Example 3 on page 940 of your textbook.